# Is it possible to connect non component Class to redux store?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-router, react-redux

So I am using a react-redux boilerplate that has an ApiClient helper. It looks like this:

```
export default class ApiClient {
  constructor(req) {
    /* eslint-disable no-return-assign */
    methods.forEach((method) =>
      this[method] = (path, withCredentials, { params, data } = {}) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const request = superagent[method](formatUrl(path))

        if (withCredentials) {
          console.log('first of all, its true')
          console.log(this)
        }

        if (params) {
          request.query(params)
        }

        if (__SERVER__ && req.get('cookie')) {
          request.set('cookie', req.get('cookie'))
        }

        if (data) {
          request.send(data)
        }

        request.end((err, { body } = {}) => {

          return err ? reject(body || err) : resolve(body)

        })
      }))
    /* eslint-enable no-return-assign */
  }
  /*
   * There's a V8 bug where, when using Babel, exporting classes with only
   * constructors sometimes fails. Until it's patched, this is a solution to
   * "ApiClient is not defined" from issue #14.
   * https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/14
   *
   * Relevant Babel bug (but they claim it's V8): https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2455
   *
   * Remove it at your own risk.
   */
  empty() {}
}
```

I want to connect this to my auth so that I can prepend headers to protected endpoints, like so:

```
@connect(state => ({ jwt: state.auth.jwt }))
export default class ApiClient {
  ...
```

However, when I do this, I get the error: `Cannot read property 'store' of undefined`. What's going on here? Why can't I connect a regular Class to the redux store?

**Update:** here's my login function, which uses the ApiClient helper:

```
export function loginAndGetFullInto(email, password) {
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch(login(email, password))
    .then(() => {
      return dispatch(loadUserWithAuth())
    })
  }
}
```

I need some way to either pass the store, or the jwt, into the `loadUserWithAuth` function...

Comment: *`connect()`: Connects a **React component** to a Redux store*. Can't you simply pass a reference to your store into your class via constructor/property?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue How so?

Comment: Something like: `var apiClient = new ApiClient(createStore()); .... constructor(store) { store.getState(); }`

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this. If you can create an answer with a bit more detail I would be very grateful. You are using a spread operator there?

Comment: As an aside, does your `ApiClient` really need to know about Redux or React? Passing a simple jwt string into it would untie it from those dependencies

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I updated my question to address that... I don't really care either way but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the jwt because it's the result of an action further up the chain of async actions...

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html . But yes, you need access to the store. How to get that is up to you.

Answer (score 27):

The `connect` function is not going to work with anything other than React components. What you can do is pass your store instance to your class and call `store.dispatch`, `store.getState`, and `store.subscribe` directly.

Keep in mind that if you subscribe, you should also have functionality to unsubscribe, otherwise your store will be holding a reference to your class instance forever, creating a memory leak.

Comment: i did not realize i could call the store constant directly. this is perfect for my app component as I was not able do a traditional connect with the app component without causing my flux router to rerender.

Comment: @ArcadeRenegade do you mind to show me how you do it?