# React class connected to the Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to figure out the way to create a plain Class, no need to be a component, since I don't need to render anything. 
The Goal is to create a class in react that is not a component but can be called from components.
This class needs to have access to the Redux Store and needs to have methods that can be called from other components.

I'm trying to create a class that will send info to Mixpanel, therefore when a user does something, views a sub-page, clicks a button, I want to call a method from the Class that will take info from the Store and send it to mixpanel.
I've tried several approaches but no luck.

I'm using [mixpanel-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mixpanel-browser) to send the info, but I don't want each component where I use this to be connected to the Store. That's why I thought of creating a Class that would be connected to the Store and she would get the info needed from there.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847699/is-it-possible-to-connect-non-component-class-to-redux-store

Answer (score 0):

You can config the store in a independent file then export it, and access it every where you wish. 
like this:

```
/**** store.js ***/
import {createStore} from 'redux'
const store = createStore(...)
export default store


/*** anywhere_you_like.js ***/
import store from './store'

//and you can access store here

class your_class{
    constructor(){
      ....
    }
    accessStore(){console.log(this.store)}
}

your_class.prototype.store = store // then you can access store from your class

/** example ***/
let a = new your_class()
a.accessStore()
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I am having issues is to create a class in react that is not a component but has to be called from components.

Comment: can you add an example on how a method of this class would be called?

Comment: I'm getting an undefined from the reducers with in the store.
Also this.store I get undefined, but store, returns {dispatch: ƒ, subscribe: ƒ, getState: ƒ, replaceReducer: ƒ, Symbol(observable): ƒ}

Comment: Did you using the same store exported form the store.js ? If that's not the case ,I'll write a example on codepen tomorrow .

Comment: Yes I did, that's what I think. Same way you did on the example.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please check my codepen example:
https://codepen.io/iamnotstone/pen/zWNzQL?editors=0010